# « Nous proposons le choix du politique [...] » : précisions ?

Tags: sens, coordination, politique

Dans un article ([« Le plus grand défi de l’histoire de l’humanité » : l’appel de 200 personnalités pour sauver la planète](https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2018/09/03/le-plus-grand-defi-de-l-histoire-de-l-humanite-l-appel-de-200-personnalites-pour-sauver-la-planete_5349380_3232.html), *Le Monde*, auteurs divers, 3 septembre 2018) on trouve la phrase suivante :

> Nous proposons le choix du politique – loin des lobbys – et des
>   mesures potentiellement impopulaires qui en résulteront.

Je ne comprends pas exactement ce que signifie « proposer le choix du    [politique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/politique) » (ni pourquoi c'est *loin des lobbys*, ni si la conjonction vient coordonner *politique* ou *lobbys*, malgré le tiret) et donc je ne comprends pas bien la phrase ; peut-on expliquer ?

- S'agit-il... :

  - ...du substantif à valeur neutre pour « tout ce qui a trait à la
    conduite des affaires de l'État » (TLFi)
  - ...de l'adjectif avec ellipse pour l'*[action](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/action) politique* dont on
    traitait plus haut dans le texte ?
  - ... d'une référence à la contrainte de l'État ?
  - ... d'un détail concernant la démission de M. Hulot ?
- À quel (nom de) choix s'oppose celui du *politique* pour pouvoir dire
  qu'on propose celui-là précisément plutôt qu'un autre ?

Comment: I don't understand it either.  The use of "Nous proposons ..." is even weird, imo (why not "demandons"?). It makes me wonder if "choix du politique" doesn't have some strange meaning here, like "politics/governance at its best/finest" and the undersigned are offering it to the world like a jeweler would offer "le choix des bijoux" to his/her best customers: "What we have to offer [ask for?] here is politics/governance at its finest ([y]our finest politics/governance) (free from special interests), along with the potentially unpopular measures resulting [necessarily] therefrom."

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks, it may be so. Both answers refer to _action politique_ (so ellipsis); it's not clear why a former paragraph has that yet in the quote _action_ wouldn't appear. It may be a renewed commitment about the body politic/State with respect to its mission, or some euphemistic societal reference about the issue being relevant at that level and not merely privately. I speculate the masc./neut. usage of _politique_ is more typical in France French than in my variety where I always expect a collocation, as adj with _action/domaine/pouvoir_. and where it's not used for a person (un) etc.

Comment: Voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31613/3177) pour un autre _appel_ qui permet probablement de mieux comprendre celui-ci. Merci !

Comment: N'y a-t-il que moi que « **lobbys** » choque, comme d'ailleurs les ***bureaus*** anglais ?

Comment: Oui, ce sont bien ces pluriels « réguliers » qui me heurtent. *Bureaus* semble beaucoup plus courant que *bureaux* en anglais (je l'ai toujours vu écrit ainsi et google ngram confirme), et je le trouve aussi ridicule que « lobbys », comme peuvent l'être « whiskys » ou « huskys » . PS: On peut se tutoyer sur FSE.

Comment: Tant que ce ne sont pas des *spaghettoes* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Les tirets pour loin des lobbys sont à prendre comme des parenthèses et loin des lobys est à prendre dans le sens "dans une direction différentes" ça donnerait quelque chose comme ça.

> Nous proposons le choix du politique (opposé à celui des lobbys) ....

Et pour la suite je serai plutôt d'avis que c'est à rattacher à l'action politique.

Pour moi la phrase aurait ce sens :
On aimerai que le pouvoir et les décisions reviennent aux hommes politiques (élus par le peuple) et non pas aux lobbys qui oeuvrent un peu dans l'ombre.

Comment: Merci ! Vous dites « on aimerait » ; si je comprends bien l'emploi du verbe _proposer_ serait comme une forme de déférence ou de politesse, un peu comme un euphémisme ? Par exemple pourquoi ne pas avoir conjugué le verbe _choisir_ ? L'emploi du verbe _proposer_ est-il d'un registre soutenu, ou est-il très évocateur en politique ?

Answer (score 1):

« loin des lobby » semble être la qualification de l'action politique particulière qui est envisagée, c'est à dire une action politique à son plus effectif, non mitigée par l'action atténuante que l'on connait comme caractéristique des lobby; il semble que la seconde partie du choix, des mesures potentiellement impopulaires, soit encore une conséquence de cette politique sans lobbys, ceux-ci étant vraiment les seuls à pouvoir ne pas être d'accord avec une politique dure.

Comment: Merci ! Serait-ce donc une critique voilée de l’interférence des lobbys sur le pouvoir public à l'intérieur d'une simple réaffirmation de ce pouvoir, de la légitimé de État ?

Comment: J'en ai bien peur, et même pas si voilée que l'on voudrait croire, seulement dans son stade initial!

Answer (score 1):

J’y comprends qu’un choix du type d’action que suivrait le groupe s’imposait, et que l’on a décidé de travailler avec des partis politiques, qui décident, plutôt qu’avec des lobbys, qui demandent ou critiquent mais construisent peu.

La base de discussion impose aussi comme prémisse, comme axiome pourrait-on dire, que tout parti ne faisant pas de la lutte aux changements climatiques son objectif premier, peu en importe les conséquences *(des mesures potentiellement impopulaires)*, ne sauraient être pris au sérieux.

Le politique serait selon moi à comprendre sous son acception de nom masculin à valeur neutre *« tout ce qui a trait à la conduite des affaires de l’État »* : on a décidé de travailler avec ceux qui dirigent ou veulent diriger l’État, pas avec ceux qui critiquent ou proposent.

Comment: Merci ! Bien ce ne sont que des questions/réponses et parfois au fur et à mesure de la rédaction on peut parfois douter de la pertinence de son propos et il m'est souvent arrivé de ne pas publier un contenu. Une réponse doit répondre à la question mais le propos original peut parfois servir à faire avancer la réflexion. Il faut se donner une chance ; rien n'est déterminant ni perdu à mon avis et il y a bien d'autres occasions et amplement de temps. Merci !