# L'« incantation » et la substantivation de l'« incantatoire » : équivalence etc. ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, adjectifs, substantivation

Dans un article sur Libération, [*Réchauffement climatique: « Nous en appelons aux décideurs politiques »*](http://www.liberation.fr/planete/2018/09/07/rechauffement-climatique-nous-en-appelons-aux-decideurs-politiques_1677176) (collectif, 7 septembre 2018) on présente le propos des auteurs ainsi :

> [...] 700 scientifiques français se mobilisent dans « Libération »,
>   exhortant les gouvernants français à passer de l’incantation aux actes
>   pour enfin se diriger vers une société sans carbone. [...]

Dans le texte, on peut lire :

> Il est tout aussi crucial qu’urgent de sortir du champ de
>   l’incantatoire et de traduire concrètement ces discours en choix
>   politiques forts et clairs au service d’une transformation sociétale
>   profonde.

Dans un cas on utilise le mot [*incantation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incantation), alors qu'ici on emploie l'adjectif [*incantatoire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incantatoire) en substantif.

L'*incantation* est une formule magique ou, par analogie, tout ce qui a un caractère mélodique, rythmique évoquant le pouvoir de l'incantation ou, au figuré, l'enchantement des sens, du coeur, de l'esprit ;  l'*incantatoire* est de la nature de/relatif à/ayant la force de... l'incantation.

---

- La sémantique de la substantivation d'incantatoire diffère-t-elle de
  celle de l'adjectif et le cas échéant comment ; quel est le nom
  générique sous-jacent sur lequel s'appuierait l'adjectif incantatoire
  pour être l'équivalent de ce substantif (par exemple, est-ce *champ*)
  ?
- *Incantation* et *incantatoire* sont-ils interchangeables dans les extraits présentés ; pourquoi/pourquoi pas ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82950/discussion-on-question-by-devastator-de-constuctors-l-incantation--et-la-subs).

Answer (score 1):

- La sémantique de la substantivation d'incantatoire diffère-t-elle de celle de l'adjectif et le cas échéant comment ; quel est le nom générique sous-jacent sur lequel s'appuierait l'adjectif incantatoire pour être l'équivalent de ce substantif (par exemple, est-ce champ) ?

Non, elle ne diffère pas de l'adjectif. Oui, le nom générique est bien *champ* : *sortir du champ de l'incantatoire* pour, par exemple, *sortir du domaine de l'incantatoire*.

- Incantation et incantatoire sont-ils interchangeables dans les extraits présentés ; pourquoi/pourquoi pas ?

Oui, ils sont interchangeables. L'auteur aurait pu écrire :

```
Il est tout aussi crucial qu’urgent de sortir de l’incantatoire etc.
```

Ici, *incantatoire* est la substantivation d'*incantation*, l'auteur aurait parfaitement pu utiliser *incantation* à la place,

```
... sortir de l'incantation ...
```

comme il l'a fait dans la permière phrase que vous citez. Je ne résiste pas au plaisir de citer la phrase de Boris Vian :

```
Je passe le plus clair de mon temps à l'obscurcir, parce que la lumière me gêne.
```

voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivation

Comment: Merci ! En reproduisant la phrase vous omettez le mot _champ_, est-ce voulu ; par exemple trouvez-vous que _sortir de l'incantation_ soit clair ? Dites-vous qu'il y a substantivation ou ellipse du générique ? Voir aussi mon commentaire sous la question avec l'idée que l'article introduise l'appel des 700 ; en d'autres mots si je comprends bien l'auteur du premier extrait est le journal(iste) alors que les 700 signent le texte contenant le deuxième extrait. Mon propos _dans un cas... alors_ ne constituait pas un appel à la cohérence mais simplement une réflexion concernant le lexique. Merci !

Comment: Clair, oui, je le pense. Concernant le verbe *sortir* voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sortir. Je suis d'accord avec https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17649/user168676 nous sommes là dans des constructions de la forme « sortir du nucléaire »

Answer (score -1):

Bien que la compréhension de l'utilisation de ces mots dans le contexte donné me paraisse sans problème et que je ne vois aucune difficulté dans l'interprétation je vais quand même vous faire part de ces idées essentielles  relatives à leur utilisation dans le présent contexte, idées qui semblent y être associées immanquablement et qui après tout pourraient déjà être évidentes pour vous; mais en ce dernier cas il y aurait quelque chose que je ne percevrais pas dans votre question.

Il n'y a aucune différence dans le sens : l'incantation, terme compris génériquement et qui aurait même pu être remplacé par « leur comportement incantatoire » puisqu'il est certain qu'il s'agit d'incantations métaphoriques sans aucun doute proférées, a possiblement été choisi pour la première référence à ce seul et même concept parce qu'il est central dans  l'identification de ce concept ; pour rompre avec la monotonie de la répétition, la seconde référence a été faite par le truchement de l'adjectif employé comme substantif ; une autre possibilité pour éviter la répétition aurait été de recourir à une formule comme « l'art incantatoire », que selon la définition de « incantatoire » on doit concevoir sans problème comme quasi-synonyme de « incantation ». Une question peut-être épineuse se présente en rapport avec l'attribut « champ » ; si, comme on peut croire au lire de votre question que vous le pressentez, un "support" semble nécessaire pour réaliser une équivalence, je ne le conçois pas comme étant « champ » mais typiquement « art » et de plus un support non obligatoire ; pour être plus spécifique en restant bref on aurait toujours à écrire « le champ de l'art incantatoire » ; les relations exprimées par la préposition « de » sont nombreuses et complexes ; dans « art de l'incantation » nous avons une relation d'apposition: cet art qui est l'incantation ; dans « champ de l'incantation » nous avons une relation d'attribut : l'incantation a un champ ; en d'autres mots l'incantation a un domaine, ce qui signifie une étendue de concept et de situations possible sur lesquels ou dans lesquels, supposément ou indubitablement elle a un effet, une raison d'être.

En cherchant une justification au mot « champ » on peut considérer la possibilité qu'il n'ait pas été utilisé et alors on aurait eu « urgent de sortir de l'incantation » ou avec un équivalent « urgent de sortir de l'art incantatoire » ; dans les deux cas on sent plus ou moins distinctement qu'une idée fausse a été représentée :  celui qui profère des incantations n'est pas dans les incantation, il n'est pas dans l'art ; il y a donc une nécessité de définir de quoi on peut sortir (si l'on choisit ce verbe) qui soit compatible avec le concept ; il y a plusieurs possibilités selon les verbes, évidemment: abandonner l'activité de proférer des incantation, couper court à la rengaine de l'incantation (apposition)… En conclusion le mot « champ » découle de l'utilisation du verbe « sortir » ou vice versa, il est impossible de dire ce que l'auteur pensait lors de la rédaction ; cependant il n'est pas une conséquence de la substantivation de l'adjectif, c'est à dire pas selon mon opinion. Soit dit en passant que cet usage qui veut que le verbe "corresponde" au concept sur lequel il porte (complément d'objet) n'est pas toujours respecté et dans des écrits moins sérieux on pourra trouver « sortir de l'incantatoire » ; on trouve souvent par exemple « sortir du nucléaire » ; on entendra aussi des choses comme par exemple  « Ils sont dans l'art. », « Elle est dans la peinture.», mais l'impression que ces énonciations laissent ne parait pas tout à fait satisfaisante.

Comment: Merci ! Je comprends parfois difficilement votre propos ; le générique est comportement ou art ou champ finalement ; voir aussi les commentaires plus haut mais notez que l'auteur du premier extrait n'est pas nécessairement le même que celui du deuxième. Par ailleurs, je pense qu'on peut noter que dans le premier extrait on se rapproche d'une locution plus figée où l'on transpose un mot similaire à celui du deuxième, mais le champ justement pour employer ce mot-là de l'incantation dans l'expression figée me semble considérablement réduit par rapport à l'adjectif subst. du deuxième. Merci !

Comment: @ dévastatordeconstuctors Non, je fais une différence entre « champ » et « art » ; le générique serait « art » selon mon point de vue, l'ensemble des procédés, des moyens et des pratiques ; le champ, comme je crois le comprendre, serait le domaine d'application et cet art lui-même; « champ » est défini comme étant d'un emploi figuré : carrière où se déploie l'activité humaine. Les protagonistes sont impliqués dans un ensemble de concepts (climat, loi, préservation…) et les abordent au moyen ou art de l'incantation ; le champ, ou carrière, est cet ensemble tel que manipulé par l'incantatoire.